# After search query highlighted in pagination is page 2

Tags: php, html, pagination

What I have is a search function. After that it would provide a paginated result. The result that I'm receiving is correct. But the problem is instead of the highlighted page is page 2. Then I tried clicking the page 1 now it is highlighted then tried clicking page 2 it gave the result for page 2. The only problem would be when clicking the search button the result highlights the 2nd page first instead of page number 1.

```
<?php
//CONTROLLER
function job_plist(){

        if($this->session->userdata('l@ginUs3r')) {

            $session_data = $this -> session -> userdata('l@ginUs3r');
            $data['u_id'] = $session_data['u_id'];
            $data['u_uname'] = $session_data['u_uname'];
            $data['u_pword'] = $session_data['u_pword'];
            $data['u_role'] = $session_data['u_role'];
            $data['is_active'] = $session_data['is_active'];
            $data['active'] = "job_plist"; 

            $table="tbl_group";
            $select="*";
            $orderby="g_name";
            $data['ddl1'] = $this -> Main -> dropdown_orderby($select, $table, $orderby);

            $table="tbl_division";
            $select="*";
            $orderby="d_divname";
            $data['ddl2'] = $this -> Main -> dropdown_orderby($select, $table, $orderby);

            $table="tbl_dept";
            $select="*";
            $orderby="dept_name";
            $data['ddl3'] = $this -> Main -> dropdown_orderby($select, $table, $orderby);

            $table="tbl_job_plist";
            $select="*";
            $orderby="jplist_id";
            $data['job_ref'] = $this -> Main -> dropdown_orderby($select, $table, $orderby);

            $table = "tbl_job_plist";
            $config = array();
            $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "personnel/job_plist/";
            //$config["total_rows"] = $this -> Main -> count_prf($table);
            if(isset($_SESSION['job_list_filter']))
            {
                $config["total_rows"] = $this -> Main -> count_prf_where($table,$_SESSION['job_list_filter']);
            }
            else
            {
                $config["total_rows"] = $this -> Main -> count_prf($table);
            }


            $config["per_page"] = 10;
            $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
            //$data["jplist"] = $this -> Main -> select_job_plist($config["per_page"], $page);
            if(isset($_SESSION['job_list_filter']))
            {
                $data["jplist"] = $this -> Main -> fetch_job_plist($_SESSION['job_list_filter'],$config["per_page"], $page);
            }
            else
            {
                $data["jplist"] = $this -> Main -> select_job_plist($config["per_page"], $page);
            }

            $data["jplist_links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

            if(isset($_POST['search']))
            {
                if($_POST['division'] != "" && $_POST['group'] != "" && $_POST['department'] != "" && $_POST['position'] != "" )
                   {
                    if($_POST['date_rec'] != "" && $_POST['date_upto'] != "")
                    {
                        $where = "jplist_div = '".$_POST['division']."' AND jplist_group = '".$_POST['group']."' AND jplist_dept = '".$_POST['department']."' AND jplist_position = '".$_POST['position']."' AND jplist_reg_date BETWEEN '".$_POST['date_rec']."' AND '".$_POST['date_upto']."' ";
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        $where = "jplist_div = '".$_POST['division']."' AND jplist_group = '".$_POST['group']."' AND jplist_dept = '".$_POST['department']."' AND jplist_position = '".$_POST['position']."' ";
                    }


                $_SESSION['job_list_filter'] = $where;
                $config = array();
                $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "personnel/job_plist/";
                $config["total_rows"] = $this -> Main -> count_prf_where($table,$_SESSION['job_list_filter']);
                $config["per_page"] = 10;
                $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
                $this->pagination->initialize($config);
                $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
                $data["jplist"] = $this -> Main -> fetch_job_plist($_SESSION['job_list_filter'], $config["per_page"], $page);
                $data["jplist_links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();  
            }

            $this -> load -> view('templates/header', $data);
            $this -> load -> view('pages/job_plist', $data);
            $this -> load -> view('templates/footer');

        } else {

            $this -> load -> view('templates/lheader');
            $this -> load -> view('pages/login');
            $this -> load -> view('templates/footer');

        }

    }
?>
```

Then on the view I have a small div for links here it is

```
<div class="pagination-align"><?=$prf_links?></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that I removed the last

```
 $data["jplist_links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

after the search then its fine.